# [Material Components iOS][TextFields] MDCTextField disabled state does not work as described in the documentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, material-design, material-components, material-components-ios

MDCTextField disabled state does not work as described in the [material design documentation](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#outlined-text-field)

I expect that the color of the disabled state should apply to the placeholder and the border.
[image]

But as a result I see only the dotted line below the color of the disabled state.
[image]

is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
@interface MyController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MDCTextInputControllerOutlined *textInputController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MDCTextField *textField;

@end

@implementation MyController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textField = [[MDCTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.f, 50.f, 220.f, 85.f)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];

    self.textInputController = [[MDCTextInputControllerOutlined alloc] initWithTextInput:self.textField];
    self.textInputController.normalColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    self.textInputController.disabledColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.textField.enabled = NO;
    self.textField.placeholder = @"placeholder";
    self.textField.text = @"text";
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put your code before init `MDCTextInputControllerOutlined` method? or do you have the option to update `MDCTextInputControllerOutlined` textfield method?

Comment: If I call `self.textField.enabled = NO;` before init `self.textInputController`, the color of the dotted line will be gray

Comment: `self.textInputController.textInput.enabled = NO;` has no effect

Comment: Do you want to grey out the color for that border? Did you text without `textfield.text = nil;`. Above material screenshot show without text. So, it's working without text I think.

Comment: If the input field is empty, then the behavior of the input field is the same. A bad decision that will help me is changing the `self.textInputController.normalColor` when changing the input fields state

Comment: "Do you want to grey out the color for that border?" - no, it should be `self.textInputController.disabledColor ` not gray, in the test case it's red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for use MDC-iOS. I can confirm this is a bug. Please create a ticket on github. It will be triaged. You can follow the issue from there or even submit a PR to correct a part of it!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. [ticket on github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/4678)